# ReactJS Firebase Hosting and Google Search Console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, seo, firebase-hosting

I've just deployed an "alpha" version of my ReactJS SPA using Firebase Hosting, and I've been trying to figure out a way to test SEO using Google Search Console. When I enter the url and click continue, it gives me the TXT record that I'm supposed to "copy into the DNS configuration" for my url. The "url prefix" wants me to upload an html file for verification, but I don't think this is even possible with a single page ReactJS app. I've done quite a bit of searching online, but haven't found a definitive solution. Could somebody please explain the proper way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: You're going to have to negotiate this change with the DNS provider that manages your domain.  If you're not using a custom domain, then you won't be able to make the necessary changes to the default DNS names given to your Firebase Hosting project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know there are different ways to connect your website files to google search console for verification. For me I opted for the older method that didn't need DNS configuration. All you had to do was copy in a meta tag you'll be given